# Can I have my testflight builds release to my internal testers before review is complete for my external testers?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an app I test on Test Flight. I have at first used only internal testers. When doing so, as soon as I upload a new build it would immediately become available to internal testers in testflight.

Now I have added an external test group. This external test group requires review before releases are available for them.

But what I have observed, is that now that I have added and external test group, that even my internal testers are not able to access builds before they are reviewed. Previously internal testers could access builds before they were reviewed.

How can I have builds release immediately for internal testers, while still having an external test group as well?

Comment: Increment the build but not the version and then review is instantaneous.

Comment: @Paulw11 app still needs a review before it can be exposed to external testers. Then after review he can just increment the build number to bypass future review requirements.

Comment: What happens when you delete the external testers group altogether? TestFlight review takes about a day or two. Maybe you should just submit it now and be done with the hassle by the weekend?

Answer (score 1):

Just 'having' external testers should not prevent you from releasing builds to internal testers.

The [current documentation](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/test-a-beta-version/enter-test-information) states:

> If you distribute your app to external testers, you need to enter additional TestFlight test information about your app for TestFlight App Review.

The [old documentation](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/en.lproj/static.html#devd8d0b6d09) states:

> If you invite external testers, the build needs to be approved by TestFlight App Review before testing can begin.

Until about a year back, this was applicable to external testers only. Internal testers still used to get access to the build immediately. I doubt that anything has changed regarding this.
However, I do not have access to an active App Store Connect account right now so I cannot validate (but you should be able to ).

In the unlikely event that Apple has changed this, you could try this workflow: Upload a build -> Add internal testers / group to the build -> They should get access to it right away, since the review is still only triggered once you add external testers -> Once you have validated that the internal testers have access add external testers to the build and trigger a review

Of course, this is a hack based on a presumed weakness in Apple's workflow (they might have made the review mandatory for both internal and external users), and I believe you will most likely not need this.

You should be able to release your build to internal testers without requiring Apple's beta review by following steps here: https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/test-a-beta-version/add-internal-testers.

Basically, create a group of internal testers (you can enable automatic distribution of new builds to true, for this group to receive every new build automatically), and then add the build to the group (or [add the group to the build](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/test-a-beta-version/add-testers-to-builds)).

You can even add individual testers to the build as described here:
https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/test-a-beta-version/add-testers-to-builds

This is if you're not interested in creating a group of internal testers.